# "Parameter is not valid" error when resizing remote image

Tags: imageresizer

Image using the remotereader plugin to resize images. The following image will render correctly in the browser when accessed directly but when access via the remotereader gives a 500 server error.

URL: http://images.britishpathe.com/?id=22797&num=55&size=thumb

GIST of the error page: https://gist.github.com/19nine78/5857810

Answer (score 0):

#### This message means the byte stream is not a valid image.

**If you download the image and attempt to resize it as a local image, do you get the same result?**

- If yes: you know that the error is due to an irregularity in the jpeg file.
- If no: then it's likely that a network-level issue, such as a reverse proxy, is modifying the byte stream and preventing the image from being parsed properly.

Comment: I downloaded the image and I **can** resize it when served locally to it does look like a network issue. The image appears to be coming from the cloudflare CDN. Is there anything that can be done in this case?

Comment: You could (a) use Wireshark, or (b) use the Immediate window while debugging to inspect the contents of the byte stream, and find out if they're sending additional header data (the most likely scenario).

Comment: I've got a wireshark capture of the image request but to be honest I'm not sure what I'm looking for in it. Is this something you'd want sent?

Comment: We'd probably have to set up a support/TeamViewer session to debug this kind of issue - doubtful we could do it over SO.